# error in a pygame code

Tags: python

```
# INTIALISATION
import pygame, math, sys
from pygame.locals import *
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
car = pygame.image.load('car.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
k_up = k_down = k_left = k_right = 0
speed = direction = 0
position = (100, 100)
TURN_SPEED = 5
ACCELERATION = 2
MAX_FORWARD_SPEED = 10
MAX_REVERSE_SPEED = ­5
BLACK = (0,0,0)
while 1:
    # USER INPUT
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if not hasattr(event, 'key'): continue
        down = event.type == KEYDOWN     # key down or up?
        if event.key == K_RIGHT: k_right = down * ­5
        elif event.key == K_LEFT: k_left = down * 5
        elif event.key == K_UP: k_up = down * 2
        elif event.key == K_DOWN: k_down = down * ­2
        elif event.key == K_ESCAPE: sys.exit(0)     # quit the game
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    # SIMULATION
    # .. new speed and direction based on acceleration and turn
    speed += (k_up + k_down)
    if speed > MAX_FORWARD_SPEED: speed = MAX_FORWARD_SPEED
    if speed < MAX_REVERSE_SPEED: speed = MAX_REVERSE_SPEED
    direction += (k_right + k_left)
    # .. new position based on current position, speed and direction
    x, y = position
    rad = direction * math.pi / 180
    x += ­speed*math.sin(rad)
    y += ­speed*math.cos(rad)
    position = (x, y)
    # RENDERING
    # .. rotate the car image for direction
    rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(car, direction)
    # .. position the car on screen
    rect = rotated.get_rect()
    rect.center = position
    # .. render the car to screen
    screen.blit(rotated, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    enter code here
```

the error i get is this  Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file race1.py on line 13, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Not able to understand what the error is and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Greg says, you have a non-ascii character in your code - what looks like a minus sign in front of the `5` on line 13. It is called 'soft hyphen'. This character appears in a few locations in your code instead of minus signs. Delete these characters and replace with minus signs.

Your code above doesn't show the character. Don't know why. When I copy and paste it into a text editor I can see the character.

If you put an encoding comment at the top of you code, for example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You will get a syntax error with the 'soft hyphen'. So you need to replace them all with minus signs. (Then you won't need the encoding comment at the top of the code.)

Answer (score 4):

You have a non-ASCII character on line 13. Python doesn't accept UTF-8 in source files unless you put a special comment at the top of your file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```